# Is String immutable in Python?

Tags: python, string, immutability

I have a question regarding String concept in Python. From my understanding Strings are an immutable part of the language. For instance:

```
a = 'Emiliano'
a[0] = 'r'
print(a)
```

Result:

```
Type Error: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

So, I know that I need to create another variable, but why in the following case doesn't Python retrieve any error if I am changing the whole string of the variable?

```
a = 'Emiliano'
a = 'David'
print(a)
```

Result: `David`

Comment: you aren't changing anything in existing string "Emiliano", while you are just reassigning the reference of string to another object.

Answer (score 1):

it's assignment, `a` point to the memory where Emiliano is, so `a=some other string` it just change the place where `a` point to

changing strings is mostly done by copy the origin string and manipulate the copy process, thus returning a new string object

Comment: @vaultah I'm talking about other methods that do manipulate strings like `replace` and such...

Comment: Thank you very much